# psycogreen exhausting postgres max_connections

Tags: postgresql, celery, psycopg2, gevent

As I'm using celery with the gevent pool, I thought that postgres might be a bottleneck (IO locks).

So I patched psycopg2 with psycogreen:

```py
import gevent
import gevent.monkey

gevent.monkey.patch_all()  # noqa

import psycogreen.gevent

psycogreen.gevent.patch_psycopg()  # noqa
```

It speeds up celery task executions (WORKER_CONCURRENCY=100 scaled to 14 instances):

```sh
celery worker -n my-queue@%h. --app=worker --loglevel=INFO --without-mingle --without-gossip -Ofair --pool=gevent --concurrency=100
```

However it almost instantly reach postgres max_connections to more than 100 connections - and get the following error: 
`OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) ERROR: no more connections allowed (max_client_conn)`

I tried to use pgBouncer to mitigate this, but it still exceeds the limit. (using the default configuration from the [kubernetes repo](https://github.com/edoburu/docker-pgbouncer/tree/master/examples/kubernetes/singleuser))

I'm using SqlAlchemy ORM:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from config import postgres_url_db

engine = sa.create_engine(
    postgres_url_db,
    pool_recycle=3600,
    pool_size=7
)
session = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(
        autocommit=False,
        autoflush=False,
        bind=engine
    )
)

db_session = session()
db_session.execute(...) # my db query
db_session.commit()
```

Any recommendations on how to better use gevent with postgres?

Comment: Using pgBouncer is the right solution. Could you post your pgBouncer configuration and/or some logs? This has nothing to do with gevent - there shouldn't be any difference for your APP to connect via pgBouncer to the Postgres.

Comment: @illagrenan I used the default configuration of the kubernetes deployment: https://github.com/edoburu/docker-pgbouncer/tree/master/examples/kubernetes/singleuser